# Exporting and importing screens and StyleSheets from separate files

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

**Background**

I've been coding each of my screens in React Native in a single file. I figured it would be much more efficient to have each screen in a file of their own. I had all 11 screens in a single file and a `StyleSheet`. The path used to be `'./app/Screens.js'`. I've created a folder within `app` called `screens`, and within that folder I have every screen in a separate file aswell as the `StyleSheet`. The new path to the `StyleSheet` is `'./app/screens/StylesPack.js'`, just to show an example.

**Problem**

First time I attempt to preview the app in expo I would get a `Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve "./screens/StylesPack.js" from "app\screens\Home.js"` error message in CMD and a `error while reading multipart response` in my phone. Figured the problem should be that I wasn't calling my `StylesPack.js` properly, so I went and changed it to `'./app/screens/StylesPack.js'` however, that didn't work either. One thing changed though, the error message in my phone now is `The development server returned response error code: 500` followed by a URL.

**Question**

Is it possible to have a setup such as this? Do I need to go back to each screen in a same file? Any ideas as to why I'm getting any of these errors?

Thanks a lot!

**Notes and edits**

Note 1: I had forgotten to change the `Home.js` path to `./app/screens/StylesPack.js`, when I did so the error message went back to `Error while reading multipart response. Response code: 200`

Note 2: Reloading the app again brings back error 500, doing it another time it goes back to error 200.

**The import/export code is:**

In App.js:

```
import {HomeScreen} from './app/screens/Home.js';
import {LoginScreen} from './app/screens/Login.js';
import {CreateAccountScreen} from './app/screens/CreateAccount.js';
import {AScreen} from './app/screens/A.js';
import {BScreen} from './app/screens/B.js';
import {CScreen} from './app/screens/C.js';
import {DScreen} from './app/screens/D.js';
import {EScreen} from './app/screens/E.js';
import {FScreen} from './app/screens/F.js';
import {GScreen} from './app/screens/G.js';
import {HScreen} from './app/screens/H.js';
```

In a specific screen:

```
import {styles} from './app/screens/StylesPack.js';
export const HomeScreen
```

In StylesPack.js:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({})

export {styles};
```

Comment: we need more info, please provide the code of how are you exporting, and importing those files

Comment: @xyaz Just edited the post to contain that :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer was really simple and I could only figure it out by slamming my head against the wall over and over. Turns out the problem was concerning how I was importing. Instead of using a "full path" as in `'./app/screens/StylesPack.js'` I simply needed to use `'../'`, so it'd be `'../screens/StylesPack.js'`

Now you may be wondering, can someone feel so stupid but so proud of himself at a specific point in time? Yes, yes someone can. I'm someone.